# If you desire to show off acts of worship but don't act on them, is it still sinful?

Tags: shirk, ibadah

I know when you worship Allah Most Great you shouldn't show off to people because it's a minor shirk or Riyaa.  If you get thoughts or desire to show off worship to people so they will praise you but you don't act on these thoughts or desire, they are just thoughts or desire in your heart but never manifest them.  Would you be still sinful by having these these thoughts and desire? even though you don't act on them.  Please provide evidence if you can. I hope I made sense.